# Fetching tweets over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am trying to embed the following code into a web page, which is supposed to be transferred via HTTPS. However, this snippet results in two requests to twitter.com, one of which is not via HTTPS, and this means that the browser gives a warning that my page "contains insecure content".

```
getTwitters('name', {
  id: 'account',
  count: 3,
  withFriends: false, 
  enableLinks: false,
  ignoreReplies: true,
  newwindow: true,
  template: '<span style="blabla">%time%</span><p style="blabla">%text%</p>'
});
```

Does anyone have an idea:

1. why there are only two calls for fetching tweets?
2. why one of them is made by insecure HTTP?
3. how to tell twitterjs to load my tweets via HTTPS only?

EDIT: I am using the library from http://code.google.com/p/twitterjs/, and yes, the js file is loaded by HTTPS.

Comment: The actual action must be taking place in an external javascript.  My best guess is that the initial external JS file is being loaded from Twitter then the function is causing it to make an ajax request.  Make sure the src attribut in the script tag is using HTTPS.  If that's not it, then look in the twitter javascript api you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the hard-encoded `http://`s to `https://`s in the library. I hate how simple things seem to be after having struggled for hours :(